# EC2 Reserved Instances - Currently have micro what to do now?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, reserved-instances

I have been running with 2 micro on demand instances. I now want to convert one of the servers  to a small instance. I have purchased a Windows small reserved instance in us-east-1b and it is now appearing under "reserved instances".

My micro instances are also in us-east-1b and are running Windows. Do I need to create another instance? I've looked at doing that but there is nowhere to select to use the reserved instance. Also, the EBS volume still says 30GB when creating that when the AWS website says it should be 160GB.

I'm confused as to what I should do. Do I simply upgrade one of my micros to a small instance and add an EBS volume? I don't want to do something, configure a server and then find out that I'm not getting the reserved rate and have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with EC2 things are like this.

You can have any number of instances running as on-demand instance, and later on if you feel comfortable, then you can move the on-demand instance to reserved instance, without need to configure the server from scratch.

Regarding the upgrading of instances, you can upgrade an on-demand instance after shutting it down, but once you make that instance reserved, you can't upgrade or downgrade it. You have to create a new instance and then make it reserve.

You won't get a option to create a reserved instance, it's just you have to create a on-demnd instance and then move it to reserved.

Feel free to comment in case you need any further info.

Comment: Thanks. On the point of moving an on-demand to reserved how would I do that? I've created a new instance which matches my reserved instance. How do I tell AWS that the instance I created should be the reserved one?

Comment: When you purchase a reserved instance, any appropriate instance will automatically be covered.  No need to "do anything" other than purchase the reserved instance.

Comment: Yes, it worked the same way as Matt described. Sorry got late in replying. Simply buy a reserved instance from the console.